# Tumblr/Oauth issues for Chrome extension, failing to get access token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth, tumblr

I'm working on a Chrome extension that uses the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), to post screenshots to a specific Tumblr site of mine. I'm using Oauth in order to do this, but am running into some problems with getting the access token from Tumblr.

The first part of the authorization process seems to be working, but it fails afterwards. I have looked at some other posts involving the same thing, mostly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579840/chrome-extension-oauth-tumblr), but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

manifest.json looks like this,

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Black Sand White Sand Grey Sand",
  "description": "An extension for art",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Click on this I dare you!"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }, 

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["blurry.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "script.js"]
    }
  ], 

  "permissions": [
    "alarms", 
    "activeTab", 
    "tabs",
    "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token",
    "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize",
    "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token",
    "http://black-sand-white-sand-grey-sand.tumblr.com/", 
    "<all_urls>"
  ], 

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "chrome_ex_oauth.html"
  ]
}
```

I downloaded the 4 files that this google tutorial gave me, (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) and I'm not sure if I'm implementing the files wrong, or if it is something in my background page that is messing up.

Here is 'background.js',

```
var image;
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
  'request_url': 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
  'authorize_url': 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize',
  'access_url': 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
  'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
  'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',
  'scope': 'http://black-sand-white-sand-grey-sand.tumblr.com/',
  'app_name': 'Black Sand White Sand Grey Sand'
});

function onAuthorized() {
  var url = 'api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/black-sand-white-sand-grey-sand.tumblr.com/post';
  var request = {
    'method': 'POST', 
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': {
      'type': 'photo',
      'state': 'published', 
      'date': 'null', 
      'source': image,
      'data': image,
      'data64': image
    }
  }

  oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, function(text, xhr) {
    console.log(text);
  });
}

function authorizeIt() {
  oauth.authorize(onAuthorized);
}


function screenshot() {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
    null, {format: 'jpeg', quality: 100}, function(dataUrl) {
      image = dataUrl;
      authorizeIt();
    });
}
```

The initial authorization works, bringing up a tab that asks for access, but when i click 'allow', it gets stuck on another redirecting page, where in the console it gives me these errors,

```
GET https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=z0lAIsL6mGl4Ib…h_token=H3x59WDyfwf9xacNrHVk9mLhVncRD0gnmdiJcnjyZXhsxY1gal&oauth_verifier= 400 (Bad Request)

Uncaught Error: Fetching access token failed with status 400
```

I also have thought that maybe it is something with 'chrome_ex_oauth.html' below, but I have no idea. I have been trying to tweak it and figure it out for the last couple days but cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 * Copyright (c) 2009 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.  Use of this
 * source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the
 * LICENSE file.
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OAuth Redirect Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font: 16px Arial;
        color: #333;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="onload.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Redirecting...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it actually the case that in the `GET /oauth/access_token` request, the `oauth_verifier` query parameter is empty? That would surely cause it to fail with a `400`. Can you also get the exact response body passed back with the `400` from tumblr?

Comment: @mitchellcliftonbarton Did you find any solution? I am getting the same error?

Comment: @Shailajashah No I never did! Tricky problem